# Use laptops touchscreen as an external monitor for my desktop

Tags: windows, laptop, touchscreen

I would like to treat my windows laptop as an external monitor for my windows desktop. There are applications like Spacedesk that allow you to use the laptop/android/ios device as an external monitor but the laptop's input is non functional.

I would like to the be able to use the touch screen on my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, sorry. The Android apps usually take advantage of some connectivity protocol like Bluetooth or WiFi - see [Spacedesk details](http://spacedesk.ph/features/)

You could use your laptop's screen for the desktop by using one of the apps designed for Windows, however all of these are one way. i.e. they will display the outgoing signal. There is no driver or protocol that would allow to use the digitizer/touch functions as a remote input for your desktop.